# Rails session cookie not working with chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-chrome, session

Ruby: 3.1.3
Rails Version: 6.1.6.1
Chrome Version: 109.0.5414.119

Setting a user_id in a cookie in a session controller, but it's not showing up on subsequent requests, and looking at the application inspector in chrome it doesn't show any cookies set.

This is the controller and function that sets the cookie

```
class Api::Auth::UserController < ApplicationController

  def create_session
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

    if user.present?
      head :unauthorized unless user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:current_user_id] = user.id
      @success = true
      debugger
    else
      head :unauthorized
    end
  end
```

No error message other than the 401 unauthorized I throw when `session[:current_user_id]` is `nil`.

Works perfectly on firefox, but for some reason Chrome doesn't persist the cookie that tries to get set.

Comment: How is `Rails.application.config.session_store` configured in your Rails application? Is it possible that sessions or cookies are disabled in your API controllers by calling a `before_action` somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better to use cookies instead of session, by the documentation at https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Cookies.html

you should be able to do it with:

`cookies[:current_user_id] = user.id`

You can also use encryption to store the value if you think this should be protected.

There are several leads for you to investigate why Chrome is not working:

- Timeout of the session
- SameSite (check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite)
- Beta versions of chrome sometimes have problems or introduce new experimental features.